# Removing element from an array list within a DTO using java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, dto, mutable

I have DTO which contains several attributes on which is of type `ArrayList`.

1. I want take this DTO as parameter.
2. Then get the attribute with `ArrayList`.
3. Then based some predicate I want to remove some elements from the `ArrayList`
4. Finally return the modified DTO

   ```
   public class SomeDTO{

   private String attrOne;
   private String attrTwo;
   private List<SomeOtherDataType> listAttr;
   // getters 
   // setter
   ...


   }

   // This is the method where I want to modify the DTO
   private void modifyDTO(SomeDTO someDTO){

    someDTO.getlistAttr()
      .stream()
      /// need help here, how to remove some element from list 
      /// based on some condition.
      /// note the changes in the list should be reflected in DTO 

   }
   ```

   This can be done by simply doing a forEach terminal operation but is there a better way to this or any best practise that others follow.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in fact you have two ways :

- collecting a new List with the elements to keep and assign it to the field
- removing element from the actual List

The second way is probably what you need for multiple reasons such :

- generally for a `List` field you don't want to create a new List to change its state. You want to that only for fields that refer to immutable objects.
- if some objects keep a reference on the `List` field, these objects will refer the old object. Which is not desirable and can create side effect issues hard to understand.
- creating the whole filtered objects may have a cost in terms of CPU/memory  while removing objects from the existing `List` is very probably more efficient.

1 way) Reassign to a new object

```
 List<SomeOtherDataType> listAttr =
 someDTO.getlistAttr()
        .stream()
        .filter(o -> conditionToKeep)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
someDTO.setListAttr(listAttr);
```

2 way) Filter in the current object

```
someDTO.getlistAttr().removeIf(o -> conditionToRemove);
```

**Edit about the OP comment**

Even if the condition to filter out element requires to dig on the `SomeOtherDataType` object and the elements that compose it , the stream is still not required.
A fancy code to illustrate that :

```
someDTO.getlistAttr()
       .removeIf(o -> {
                        Bar bar = o.getFoo().getBar();
                        if (bar != null){
                            List<FooBar> fooBars = bar.getList(); 
                            if (fooBars.contains(...)){
                                 return true; // I remove in this case
                            }
                        }
                        return false; // in any other case I keep
                      }
                );
```

Comment: The code I gave above is just a sample code. The attribute List<SomeOtherDataType> is actually not directly available in SomeDTO there are many other attributes and which in turn has list as son on. 

So to get SomeOtherDataType I anyway has to do a stream and reach there, so if I have to to set to a  the filtered list I have to again use stream and get to SomeOtherDataType and then do call setter as us suggested.

Is it good practice to do so ? as we are traversing the stream two times.

Comment: It is not a bad practice but it may have some side effects or limitations as stated in my answer. While I am not quite sure that the stream be unavoidable. Maybe you should edit your code.

Comment: @Shahbaz Khan Great if it could help you :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use streams here. You can simply use [Collection.removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-).

From the javadoc (emphasis mine)

> **Removes all of the elements of this collection that satisfy the given predicate**. Errors or runtime exceptions thrown during iteration or by the predicate are relayed to the caller.

Hence, you can write

```
someDTO.getlistAttr().removeIf((someOtherDataType) -> /*Your logic here*/)
```

---

If you really want to use Streams, then from where you have left, you can use a `filter` and collect the `SomeOtherDataType` elements that pass the filter as a list.

```
List<SomeOtherDataType> filterdList =  someDTO.getlistAttr()
   .stream()
   .filter(someOtherDataType -> /* your logic */)
   .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

But after this, you would either have to

1. Create a new `SomeDTO` with the above `filterdList` (`new SomeDTO(someDTO.getAttrOne(), someDTO.getAttrTwo(), filterdList)`)<sup>1</sup> or
2. Set the existing `listAttr` with `filterdList` (`someDTO.setListAttr(filterdList)`)

<sup>1</sup> I think you meant the name of the second instance variable to be `attrTwo`.